# PHP select data from table, not working

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so i don't really know PHP, when someone submits a form, it needs to check if that datetimestamp is already in the mysql table or not then do something.

localhost.php:

```
<?php 
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "bookings";
$username_localhost = "username";
$password_localhost = "password";
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
?>
```

Main file:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookingtable` WHERE `Date of Session` = '$date'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 'the date was found, please try another';
} else {
    echo 'the date wasnt found';
};
?>
```

It used to work but now it just always says thats it's not in the table when it actually is.

Comment: before if stmnt: if(!$result){ die(mysql_error()); }

Comment: `echo 'the date wasn't found';` you have a syntax-error here, you have to escape the apostrophe or use double quotes, like this: `echo "the date wasn't found";` Also, you use `$result` for the query, but you use `$result15` when checking the number of rows.

Comment: @Qirel those are just errors i made typing this in they aren't actually in the real code

Comment: @alamnaryab i've added that now all im getting is 'No database selected'

Comment: sorry I have edited my comment: you have not written select_bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the following line at end of localhost.php

```
mysql_select_db($database_localhost);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, would've never figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Localhost.php

```
   <?php 
        $hostname_localhost = "localhost";
        $database_localhost = "bookings";
        $username_localhost = "username";
        $password_localhost = "password";
        $tablename_localhost = //your name of your table from database
        $localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $tablename_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
   ?>
```

Main.php

```
    <?php require_once('../Connections/localhost.php');


     $date = $_POST['date'];

     $result = mysql_query($localhost, "SELECT * FROM bookingtable WHERE Date of Session = '$date'");

     if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         echo 'the date was found';
     } else {
          echo 'the date wasnt found';
     };
 ?>
```